# list to json object using json.net

Tags: c#, javascript, json.net

I am using json.net to convert currency rates to json.

The C# entity got a Name and a Value, where Name is USD, GBP and so one, and Value the currencyrate.

I don't know the index of the different currencies, so in javascript I want to get a currency by saying `var a = obj["USD"];` insead of looping through an array and find `array[i].name == "USD"`.
The default output of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currencyList);` is:

```
[
    {"name": "one",   "pId": "foo1", "cId": "bar1"},
    {"name": "two",   "pId": "foo2", "cId": "bar2"},
    {"name": "three", "pId": "foo3", "cId": "bar3"}
]
```

I would however like something like:

```
{
    "one":   {"pId": "foo1", "cId": "bar1"},
    "two":   {"pId": "foo2", "cId": "bar2"},
    "three": {"pId": "foo3", "cId": "bar3"}
}
```

Is this possible to acheieve with json.net, or do i need to write my own parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<String, DataType> dictionary = list.ToDictionary(d => d.name);
```

Replace `DataType` by the type of your entity.

Then, you can serialize the dictionary using json.